# How to create these Effects in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, photoshop-effects

Please help me recreate this effect

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to state which aspect you want to recreate or are struggling with and what you already know/tried.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this, is by applying the transform tool  to each one of your graphic elements. By doing this you can manipulate the figure to get the perspective you need. If you need some visual guidance, you can trace before vanishing points.

Texts will remain editable if you need to change anything.

Edit > Transform > Skew

Answer (score 1):

In photoshop one can simply draw the box (=single layer) and add the texts. The drawing is quite easy to make onto your model image. Insert the model as a layer, make it a little gray by reducing the contrast:

[image]

Create a new layer. Select it and draw over the model. Make area selections with the Polygonal Lasso tool and fill the areas with the Paint Bucket tool. You need only black and two shades of cyan:

[image]

Take the Type tool. Select a proper font and white color. Type the texts for different walls as separate textboxes. Be sure to have a big font size. It's no good to stretch the text much bigger when it's rasterized. Making it smaller is less harmful.

[image]

Drag your textboxes to their places. Rotate, scale, skew and distort them to fit. Those transformations are found from Edit > Transform. Unfortunately  sometimes the final tuning needs Distort which is not selectable until you rasterize your texts. To avoid quality loss do not rasterize before you have used other transformations as far as possible.

NOTE: This job does not need distort due the lack of perspective.

If you understand the "Smart objects" you should in the very beginning convert the text layers to them. Smart ojects stand geometrical transformations without accumulating the unsharpness. They are not in use here.

[image]

Final test with black background:

[image]

Not the highest quality and can't be enlargened without loss of quality. This job is much easier in Illustrator. Everything would there be geometrically exact and the result could be enlargened with no quality loss.